# Running a continuous Python script from PhP an reload page while executing

Tags: php, python

```html
<?php 
  $time=$_GET[ 'time'];
  $date=$_GET[ 'date'];
  if($time !="" & $date !="" ){ 
    $hour=s ubstr($time,0,2);
    $minute=s ubstr($time,3,2);
    $day=substr($date,8,2);
    $month=substr($date,5,2);
    $year=substr($date,0,4);
    $execute=exec("python ..\alarm.py $year $month $day $hour $minute"); 
  }
?>


<form action="index.php" method="get">
  <input type='date' name='date'>
  <input type='time' name='time'>
  <input type='submit' value='setAlarm'>
</form>
```

So i am working on some Code that should do the following:

1. Clicking a Submit-button on my index.php should execute a python-script stored on the Server and submitting the params of the form
2. The python script, which is a script that is continuously excecuting an alarm (it sets an alarm an waits until then to execute it -> so it is supposed to run until the alarm is finished)
3. After the python script was started from the php script, the index.php should reload.

Right now, it all works without the reloading of the index.php. The file is being executed and after manually reloading the page, the index.php Shows me all running alarm.py scripts, which is all i want.

So is there a way, to force the reloading of the page, after the executing from php started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "&" et the end :

```
exec("python ..\alarm.py $year $month $day $hour $minute &");
```

Comment: Made it with adding "> /dev/null 2>/dev/null &" to the end of my exec command.